# Would "Diet of Worms" seem strange to English-Speakers at the time?

Tags: martin-luther, reformation

Today, the phrase brings to mind the eating of slimy invertebrates. Did it at the time of the Diet of Worms. Do we have any records from the time of people making clever comments about the phrase?

I believe "diet" was first used for food, but I can't find anything specifically.

Answer (score 1):

People who are aware of the Latin origin of the political terminology "Diet" (from the Latin *dieta* to mean [formal deliberative assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_(assembly))), especially in Germany where the first thing that came to mind for "Worms" is the ancient city of [Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worms,_Germany) which existed since the pre-Roman times, would *not* have thought of "Diet of Worms" like you do.

Your assertion that "diet" was first used for food, is [wrong etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_(assembly)#Etymology), as "daily food allowance" came from another Latin word *diaeta*.

To English speakers at the time of Luther, the meaning of "diet" as "assembly of delegates" (see [diet (n.2)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/diet) from the Online Etymological Dictionary) would have been a lot more obvious than today where the meaning is a lot less prominent.